# Use Excel Conditional Formatting Data Bars to show percentage change of value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I would like to add conditional formatting data bars that show the percentage change based on each value in column E. For example in row 25, E25 would be 0%, D25 would be ~50% and C25 would be ~75%. I want to do this for each row. If it's a negative change then it would show a different color. Is this possible? I have been trying and searching for hours and can't figure it out. Would I have to create a new rule for each set?

[Screenshot of Excel report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0eGV.png)

Comment: Take it a step at a time. What's the equation (formula) for coming up with the percentage in each column?

Comment: For row 25: C25 =(C25-E25)/E25*100; D25 =(D25-E25)/E25*100; E25 =(E25-E25)/E25*100

Answer (score 0):

So you have the formulas that you need. You can apply that formula to the whole column if you like, but start like this...

1. Select cell `D25`, then choose Home-->Conditional Formatting-->Manage Rules...
2. Click "New Rule... " then "Use a formula t determine which cells to format"
3. Now enter your formula for D25 into the area then choose your format. It's **important** that your formula evaluate to True/False. Do this by adding **">0"** to the end. Mine looked like this:

[image]

4. Next, click "New Rule..." again and enter the same formula, except make it **"<0"** this time. Your rules should look like this:

[image]

5. From here you should be able to click "OK" and have your data look like this:

[image]

6. WITHOUT CHANGING THE FORMULA, you should be able to extend this formatted area by changing the "Applies To" area next to each rule. For example, make it `=$D$25:$D$50` or whatever you need.
7. Follow the same steps for your other columns. You already have the formulas.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the walkthrough. I will try it, but I don't see how this uses the data bars formatting type. High level, I want to be able to quickly glance through these to see the accounts that had a high % change from the prior years. If the bars are small I know there wasn't a significant change but if the bar fills the cell then there was.